# View not getting rendered - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to render templates inside a main view. Here is the Feed, which is my main view.

```
<ion-view view-title="Feed">
  <ion-content scroll="true">
    <div ui-view="opportunity"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I'm trying to render Opportunity inside my Feed. Here is the code for Opportunity. The template is named as `card-opportunity.html`

```
<h1>Opportunity Details</h1>
```

In the `app.js` I have included the views for opportunity. I'm using `$stateProvider`

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.feed', {
  url: '/feed',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html',
      controller: 'FeedCtrl'
    },
    'network' : {
      templateUrl: 'templates/card-network.html',
      controller: 'CardNetworkCtrl'
    },
    'opportunity' : {
      templateUrl: 'templates/card-opportunity.html',
      controller: 'CardOpportunityCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Not sure what I'm missing. There is no error in the console. I'm using `ionic: 3.7.0`

Comment: post your module code

Comment: @Sajeetharan Updated with the code. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…
 **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views
says this:-

*"Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view."*
I am not sure if a view will load if you give its ui-sref in its sibling view. Why don't you create a new state for the opportunity ,so that it loads as a child of the feed.

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('app.feed', {
     url: '/feed',
     views: {
       'menuContent': {
         templateUrl: 'templates/feed.html',
         controller: 'FeedCtrl'
       },
       'network' : {
         templateUrl: 'templates/card-network.html',
         controller: 'CardNetworkCtrl'
       }
  }
})

 .state('app.feed.opportunity',{
     url: '/opportunity',
    views: {
       'opportunity' : {
          templateUrl: 'templates/card-opportunity.html',
          controller: 'CardOpportunityCtrl'
     }
  }
});
```